# Azure B2C - Custom Policy - Error connecting identity provider DocCheck

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I Have been trying to add a OAuth2.0 custom policy for Azure AD B2C to connect with External IDP (DocCheck).

Same policy has google claim provider also which is working. I have verified ClientId And ClientSecret with DocCheck app registration and redirect URL also looks good.

This is Claim Provider configuration for doccheck

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="docCheck-OAUTH2">
  <DisplayName>DocCheck</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ProviderName">login.doccheck.com</Item>
    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.doccheck.com/code/de/************/fullscreen_dc/</Item>
    <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://login.doccheck.com/service/oauth/access_token/</Item>
    <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://login.doccheck.com/service/oauth/user_data/</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    <!-- <Item Key="scope">email profile openid</Item> -->
    <!-- <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
    <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item> -->
    <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
    <Item Key="token_endpoint_auth_method">client_secret_post</Item>
    <!-- <Item Key="scope">https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.readonly</Item> -->
    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>

    <Item Key="client_id">**********</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_DocCheckSecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <!-- <InputClaims> -->
    <!-- <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="access_type" PartnerClaimType="access_type" DefaultValue="offline" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" /> -->

    <!-- The refresh_token is return only on the first authorization for a given user. Subsequent authorization request doesn't return the refresh_token.
         To fix this issue we add the prompt=consent query string parameter to the authorization request-->
    <!-- <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" PartnerClaimType="prompt" DefaultValue="consent" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" /> -->
  <!-- </InputClaims> -->
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="address_name_first" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="address_name_last" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="address_name_first" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="docheck.com" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />

    <!-- The unit test's claims-->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Access_token" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Expires_in" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:expires_in}" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Token_type" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:token_type}" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I am getting following error.

> AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.
> Correlation ID: 188d934d-f1f0-48c5-98c4-917b032b94d2
> Timestamp: 2019-11-29 10:54:49Z

Followed this documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom?tabs=applications.

Calling AccessTokenEndpoint directly with code returned from auth endpoint with same client id and secret, I am able to get the token from postman.

[image]